# Estimating the overall proportion of people who will vote for an individual after sampling two unique groups

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say you have two disjoint groups of people, $A$ and $B$, in an entire population. Out of the overall population, the proportion of people in group $A$ is $q$. We want to determine what the overall fraction, $p$, of people who will vote for an individual is.

If we survey $N_a$ people from group $A$ and $N_b$ people from group $B$, assuming the votes for him are distributed i.i.d. Bernoulli $p_a$ and $p_b$ for each group, how would you find a $90\%$ confidence interval for $p$?

I've seen things dealing with the difference, and just a single group, but not sure how to expand this to a more general case. Can you just do a linear combination of the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sampling technique is random over the whole population, you can just combine your sample results. So, if $v_a$ people from the $N_a$ would vote for the candidate, and $v_b$ people from the $N_b$ would vote for the candidate, you estimate $p$ with $$\hat p = { {v_a +v_b} \over {N_a + N_b} }  \cdot  $$ There are many techniques to find a confidence interval for $p$ from this - I assume you already know a way to do it.

Comment: Is it valid do two confidence intervals, one for each subset, add the upper and lower boundaries for each - scaled by their relative proportions - and divide by $N_a + N_b$?

Comment: Is the proportion, q, irrelevant?

Comment: I don't think it is valid to do two confidence intervals and add boundaries, but you could test this hypothesis using simulation. Yes, the proportion $q$ is irrelevant as long as your sample is random over the whole population.